# Extract a number from a string

Tags: regex, string, visual-c++

I am a java programmer and quite new to visual c++. I want to extract two integers from a CString like below.

Segments: [1  inlet section] to [10  RC axial bend]

I want to extract the no. 1 and 10 from the string and their positions will always be after a "[" but the no.of letters in the string may vary.

Can I use regex? I found that I need a library like "Boost" in order to use regex. Is there an easy way other than using a library to do this? Please give me your ideas.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use strtok to tokenise the string then use atoi to get the numbers from the tokens

*Edit:*

This is very simple and has no error checking.

```
void getNumbers(CString inputString, int & number1, int & number2)
{
    char tempBuf[300];
    strcpy(tempBuf, inputString.GetBuffer());
    char * startString = strtok(tempBuf,"[");
    char * num1String = strtok(NULL,"[");
    char * num2String = strtok(NULL ,"[");
    number1 = atoi(num1String);
    number2 = atoi(num2String);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jet. Can you give me any example?